# Generate random code with cookie

Tags: random

I want to generate a random code with 22 digits including uppercase letters and numbers. The code should have something like a cookie so that it remains the same and doesn't change once someone opens the web site in his browser again.

Is that possible with PHP? If yes, does someone has a snippet for that?

Thanks in advance!

Regards

Comment: If you want something like a cookie, why not just look up how to make a cookie and use that?

Answer (score 1):

That IS exactly the purpose of a cookie ([see php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php)): to recognize users and store data for/about them.

If saving for one browser session (as long as the user does not close his browser) is enough, you might want to create [a session](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php).

PHP is normally executed per request and dies at the end of a request. Therefore, it has no memory. Of course, you might try to store the user's IP address into a file on your webserver for later retrieval. However, this is most likely not very reliable (multiple users might have the same IP, if they are behind a proxy).

Comment: +1 Also, many people have dynamic IPs that can change multiple times per day.